# Adobe Air IPA errors new icons size IOS7

Tags: flash, air, icons, ios7, ipa

I devloped a application to IOS 7 by adobe air 3.9, but i was having problem with new icons when i try to generate an IPA.

I have everything ok and i executed the follow commands:

c:\airsdk\bin\adt -package -target ipa-debug -keystore ios_distribution.p12 -storetype pkcs12 -storepass XXXXX -provisioning-profile integru6.mobileprovision index.ipa index-app.xml index.swf icons Default.png

but this command returned icon size errors:

...-app.xml: error 103 : application.icon.image76x76....

I put the icons size informations inside a "...app.xml" and executed any SDK platafoms Air SDK (3.9.0.720, 3.9.0.960, 3.9.0.1030, 3.9.0.1080)... it displays the same error...

Anybody knows how to generate the IPA with the news icons IOS7 ???

I tried this ...app.xml icons config

...
icons/icon76.png
...

**OR**

...
icons/icon76.png
...

Thanks so much

André

Comment: AIR3.9 should be able to handle the new icon sizes. what happens if you try and publish with 3.8?

Comment: Could we get the full error message as well as the `<icon>...</icon>` section of your app.xml? @LeeBurrows Publishing with 3.8 is useless at this point. Apple will reject any app not built with 3.9+ because of the new icons.

Comment: @Josh - not useless; its called debugging

Comment: I tried to use all versions of Air SDK, and the error is the same

Comment: <icon><image76x76_iOS7>icons/icon76.png</image76x76_iOS7></icon>

Comment: <icon><image76x76>icons/icon76.png</image76x76></icon>